# How to ADD encoding in RSTUDIO

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

I've installed RSTUDIO on the another machine with another Windows version and cannot see encoding which I used on the previous computer (CP1251).
When opening "Reopen with encoding" I don't see CP1251. How can I add it to R or Windows maybe?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `Tools > Global Options... > Code > Saving` tab check `Show all encodings`

[image]

And they will all show up. OK and that's it.

[image]

Comment: I'm stupid like a tree. Thanks!